# Access permissions for google-compute-engine script

Tags: ssh, chown, google-cloud

I would like to run a python script on compute engine, which uses a Linux-based operating system ("debian-9-stretch-v20180307").  I am using a bash boot script with code as follows:

```
#! /bin/bash

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -yq install python-pip
sudo pip install --upgrade google-cloud
sudo pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage
sudo pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
sudo pip install --upgrade google-auth-httplib2

echo "Making directories..."

mkdir -p /home/<myusername>/code
mkdir -p /home/<myusername>/rawdata
mkdir -p /home/<myusername>/etc...

sudo chown -R <myusername> /home/<myusername>

echo "Directory creation complete..."

gsutil cp gs://<mybucketname>/worker-python-code/* /home/<myusername>/code/
gsutil -m cp gs://<mybucketname>/* /home/<myusername>/rawdata/

echo "Boot complete."
```

When I create an instance and it boots using the script, all directories are created as intended and all data is copied per the gsutil commands.  I then "SSH" into the instance and the following command to run my script:

```
python '/home/<myusername>/code/workermaster.py'
```

The script runs, until it gets to a line which requires it to create .csv on the disk, and then I get an "[Errono 13] Permission denied" error.

I have done a few tests and attempts to get the script running when run an SSH shell based on other threads and google searches but cannot seem to get it working.  Some interesting notes and observations are:

1)  In the "console output" reports there is a line which reads:

```
chown: invalid user: ‘<myusername>’
```

And then many lines down it states:

```
Created user account <myusername>
```

Which suggests I am trying to set ownership to someone who doesnt exist yet, but I cant work out what to do about it.

2)  If I run the "chown" command line after logging in via SSH and then run my script, it runs exactly as intended with no issues.

3)  I tried to fix the issue by adding a line to the boot script which read:

sudo chmod -R 777 /home/

When I used this command, I couldnt even SSH into the instance.

Ultimately I plan to add "nohang up" line to the script so that the python code runs remotely without me logging in, but I need to understand what is happening here and to be able to just SSH in and run my script following boot.

Comment: Do you absolutely *need* to have this as a boot script? Can it not be added after boot? The problem is that users aren’t created until the machine has finished booting up. If the user doesn’t exist, then you can’t assign ownership of dirs/files.

Comment: You could always create the user before you chown... but that might cause an error when gcp tries to create your user later on.

Comment: Thank you for the response dijksterhuis.  I definitely need a boot script, but I guess its not the worst thing in the world if I need to just type the "chown" line after boot.  For info, I tried running the code using the "nohup" command line from the boot script, and it runs fine, so really this is just a nice to have.  For the sake of completeness I will try your suggestion of creating the user and assigning ownership, and see if it causes GCE to trip up, just out of interest!

Comment: I’d be interested to hear what happens too...

Comment: Was there any solution after all? I wrote a startup script which refers to $USER and could check in `syslog` that `systemd` runs after the startup script, so no way to refer $USER into startup scripts

Comment: Hi manasouza, in the end I was not able to get this working.  If I wanted to SSH into the instance any run my python scripts "manually", I needed to run the sudo chown command line to assign ownership of the folders once I had logged in.  If I just ran the script using "nohup" then the instance works remotely with no problem.